# Angular with ng-if at directive template, it is change scope method/variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

i found a sample at angular official documentation about directive which fit to me for Tab element creation. The url is : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive at section "Creating Directives that Communicate". It is about "Tab" interface. However i need to have small modification to it.

Basically i need 2 type of "Tab". 1st is just like the sample there which i define the `tabType` as `tab`, 2nd i need only the tab header without panes then i define the `tabType` as `url`. The one with `tabType` defined as `url` supposed to be have link to another page when click on it.

What i am doing now to achieve that is, i put a variable / parameter named `tabType` at the tab header directive scope to distinguish both of type i want to have. And put `ng-if` at the template for pane wrapper to make it available only when `tabType` is `tab`. Below is the snippet of 2 directives i have made, and available at [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bMTjiYCXHYtZS7temj4F?p=preview) :

```
  var bngapp=angular.module('BApp',[])
  .controller('BCtrl', function($scope){
      angular.element(document).ready(function(){

      });
  })
  .directive('biqTab', function(){//named biqTab
      return {
      restrict : 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope : {
          tabType : '@'//tab/url
      },
      controller : ['$scope', function($scope){
          var self = this;
          var panes = $scope.panes = [];

          $scope.click = function(pane) {
          angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
              pane.selected = false;
          });
          pane.selected = true;
          };
          self.addPane = function(pane) {
          if (panes.length === 0) {
            $scope.click(pane);
          }
          panes.push(pane);
          };
      }],
      template: '<div class="biq-tab">\n\
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">\n\
        <li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">\n\
          <span ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</span>\n\
        </li>\n\
          </ul>\n\
          <div>Tab type: {{tabType}}<br> Child length:{{panes.length}}</div>\n\
          <div ng-if="tabType===\'tab\'" class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>\n\
        </div>'
      };
  })
  .directive('biqTabItem', function(){
      return {
      require: '^^biqTab',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        title: '@', url:'@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, biqTabCtrl) {
          biqTabCtrl.addPane(scope);
      },
      template: '<div class="tab-pane" ng-show="selected">test item\n\
          <div ng-transclude></div>\n\
        </div>'
      };
  });
```

At the HTML element i do this:

```
  <div ng-controller="BCtrl">
    <biq-tab tab-type="url">
        <biq-tab-item title="Frontpage" url="biqsoft.com">

        </biq-tab-item>
    </biq-tab>
  </div>
```

**The problem is**, when i change the `tabType` to 'url', then the panes.length detected as 0 even it has child element on it, as seen on my page at [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bMTjiYCXHYtZS7temj4F?p=preview). I was thinking that any change at template like with my `ng-if` will not affect variables at scope. Notice that if i change the `ng-if` with `ng-show` it will be fine as i expected, however i still trying to make it really not exist if the `tabType` is 'url' by using `ng-if`.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ngIf executes at priority 600 and your directives execute at priority 0, so ngIf runs before your directives. The purpose of ngIf is the conditional creation of elements. When you set the type to URL the elements are never created and your directive instances never link because they don't exist, as expected. Since none link none are added and the count is 0.

To learn more about ngIf go here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

To get an answer, ask a question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your clear answer. It is make sense to me about that `ng-if` not executed. But the `<div>` scope outside the `ng-if` which is `<div>Tab type: {{tabType}}<br> Child length:{{panes.length}}</div>` also seem affected by ng-if. Which it should be `1` since there is one child of the tab declared at HTML element. But it show `0` when i am using `ng-if`. When i change `ng-if` with `ng-show` then it give `1` as i expected. In my mind `panes` variable should not affected by template at it scope. Can you give me explanation about it? thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait, seem i have wrong understanding about `addPane(scope)` that i was thinking it will added just by create <biq-tab-item> element. But seem it must actually created too at the template of it parent for executing `addPane(scope)`. Is it that what you are trying to explain to me?